# Is there a way to clear a cell of any text based on the format of the cell (without formula or vba if possible)?

Tags: excel, replace, conditional-formatting

I'm working with numerous documents that have conditional formatting which turn a cell black if a certain value in the row is contains a specific text. The specific text varies a very often and will differ per document. When I try to write something in the black cell, it will automatically decline anything, but when I copy paste something on there it still enters the value. Because I have to copy big sets of data into these documents, I sometimes end up with values in these black cells, which can cause problems later on.

What I was wondering is if there is a way to delete any text in the cells that have the specific formatting (aka they are black) with help of the Find and Replace function or something similar.

Because I have to do it in seperate documents that I get from other people, I don't think using a formula or vba would be too practical, as I would need to manually copy it each time. But feel free to prove me wrong.

EDIT:
Hopefully this will illustrate more what my problem is.
[image: The Background of these cells are still considered to be 'No Fill']

The Background of these cells are still considered to be 'No Fill'

[image: The conditional formatting is what causes the color]

The conditional formatting is what causes the color

Comment: You will need to write a VBA macro

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Well what kind?

Comment: An event-triggered macro.

Comment: If you write the VBA routine in your own personal.xlsx file you will not have to copy and paste it for each use. You can even add a symbol on the formula bar which will execute it with one click.

Comment: Apparently even in a VBA routine it isn't that easy to determine if a conditional format is active for a cell or not; here's someone who's actually done it: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm

Comment: @cph In more modern versions of Excel, you can use the `Range.DisplayFormat` property to determine the color for a VBA macro (as well as testing for the underlying condition).

Comment: Thank you Ron Rosenfeld, I hadn't noticed that was an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the formatting you are trying to empty content from is yellow background cells

See image below:

[image]

1. Press Ctrl+H for Replace Option
2. Press Format Button to select the required format (yellow background)

[image]

3. Press Replace All

Final Result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if I manually colored the background of a cell. It doesn't work for cells that are colored via conditional formatting.